# iptables prerouting to multiple ports

Tags: iptables, snmp

I want to redirect SNMP traps.

Let's say, receive an SNMP trap on UDP port 162, and redirect the package to ports 10162 and 20162 (both of them). How can I achieve this using iptables?

I can successfully redirect the package to port 10162 using:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10162
```

Is it possible to redirect the package to two ports?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPTABLES: process a packet locally and send a copy to another host](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/377407/100397)

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks so much @roaima

Comment: I hope so. If not, I'll happily withdraw the suggestion and we can continue on here, but you'd need to make it clear in your question why that wasn't a suitable answer.